# Create private pages in GitHub for Doxygen documentation

Tags: github-pages, jekyll

I develop an iOS app and I comment my code in Doxygen style. I would use the feature "pages" proposed by GitHub but unfortunately, pages can't be private.

After searching on Google, I saw this POST - [Private pages for a private Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748082/private-pages-for-a-private-github-repo)

Regarding the Joel Glovier's answer, I can use Jekyll to create private pages on GitHub.

Can Jekyll manage Doxygen doc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to GitHub Pages documentation:

All project repositories are ready to use the generator for publishing. However, please note that private repositories will publish pages that are public.

There is no way to create private GitHub pages, even from a private GitHub repository.

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it does not solve my problem. I would like to run doxygen doc from code, and host it on a webserver with private acces each time I push on github. Do you know a way to do that ?

Comment: You can accomplish this with help of Git hooks. Git hooks let you fire custom commands after push. The question is too broad to answer otherwise.